# Equivalent of Application.UserLibraryPath in Excel for Mac 2004?

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel, vba

[This page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CreateAddIn.aspx) on "Creating An XLA Add-In For Excel" indicates that the folder referenced by the Application.UserLibraryPath property is the right place to save a user-defined add-in. However, in Excel 2004 for Mac, that property doesn't seem to be defined for the Application object.

Does anyone know if there's an equivalent concept in that variant of Excel? It wouldn't necessarily have to be a property of a VBA object, but just a common place to put user-defined Add-Ins that Excel will reliably consult.

There *is* an Add-Ins folder (`/Applications/Microsoft Office 2004/Office/Add-Ins/`), but my instinct is that that folder is for vendor-supplied add-ins, not user-defined ones.

(Or am I just being overly cautious? Should I just save my add-in to that `Add-Ins/` folder and call it good?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft KB has this article:[How to use Excel startup folders in Excel for Mac](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259921) which gives information on the use of the startup folders for the Mac, one use mentioned is for add-ins

(from the article)
**Add-Ins**

Add-Ins that you put in a startup folder do not typically appear when you start Excel, but are loaded into memory and run any auto macros.
   You can then use these Add-Ins by whatever method the add-in provides (that is, a menu item or toolbar button).

Comment: Thank you. I probably would never have figured this out myself. The best part is, when I move my add-in to the Startup folder, Excel finds it, just as advertised. (This also answers another question that's been in the back of my mind for a while, namely: "Where does Excel store my Personal Macro Workbook?" Turns out that it's in the  Startup folder.)

Comment: Interestingly, now that I look again at the documentation for UserLibraryPath, I see that it's "where the COM add-ins are installed." Since COM add-ins presumably don't exist in the Mac environment, I guess it makes sense that UserLibraryPath wouldn't be defined there. This also suggests that the folder referenced by UserLibraryPath isn't _really_ the right place to install VBA-based add-ins for Excel on Windows, although it probably works.

Comment: @Hephaestus, this gives some info for the windows version: https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-add-in-programs-HP005238607.aspx

Comment: Yeah, a little touring from that point of departure confirmed for me that COM add-ins are _definitely_ a Windows-only concept. As for the two installation folder options offered for "Excel" add-ins, neither of them map precisely to folders in the Microsoft Office 2004 hierarchy on Mac (the "AddIns" folder on Windows is per-user, whereas "Add-Ins" on Mac04 is installation-wide; and there's no Office/Library folder at all on Mac04). All that said, I'm happy with the original Startup folder solution, since it means that there's no manual loading step -- my add-in loads automatically.